# UIStackView leading and trailing alignment does not work when the current alignment is center

Tags: swift, iphone, uistackview

I have a case in which I need to update Stackview alignment programmatically based on the condition i.e leading, trailing, and center

It is working as expected when I change alignment from leading to trailing or vice versa but it is not working if change alignment from center to leading or trailing.

I have set default StackView property as per below:

```
stackView.alignment = .trailing
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.distribution = .fill
```

I am trying to change alignment using UISegment control, [here is a sample code link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r9TYDjZ2UXxukD7Ky2kXj5sTct_BC6IU/view?usp=sharing)

```
@IBAction func segment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
                stackView.alignment = .leading
            case 1:
                stackView.alignment = .center
            case 2:
                stackView.alignment = .trailing
            default:
                break
            }
        }
```

**Problem:**  Button width is automatically increasing when I change alignment from center to leading or trailing programmatically even if I have set a fixed width to the button

I am attaching here [video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G9t53XHRJbuYMRBbLj4Y33jXiw6nDLHl/view?usp=sharing) for your reference.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you show some code? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: You can do it without the `UIStackView`. You can just activate and deactivate your constraints, but for your case if you still want to use `UIStackView`, try `distribution = fillProportionally`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, here is my sample code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r9TYDjZ2UXxukD7Ky2kXj5sTct_BC6IU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please post your code by [edit]ing your question. Questions should be self contained.

Comment: @Rob I tried the `distribution = fillProportionally`, still have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely classify this as a "bug."

If you want a quick, easy work-around, add an empty `UIView` - constrained to size `0x0` - to the stack view:

[image]

Stack view settings:

[image]

Because the added view has no Height, and the stack view spacing is `0`, it will not be visible and will not affect the dimensions of the stack view.

Comment: I just tried work-around what you suggested, It is working as expected but I would love to know the reason behind it, and why it was not working without adding another view to the stack.

Comment: Well, first, nothing is "perfect" -- and this is not the first bug I've seen with `UIStackView`. Second, stack views are designed to **arrange** their subviews -- so, I would say a **single** arrangedSubview is an unusual case. There are many different ways to do what you're doing, so using a stack view may not be the best approach. As to why this "fixes" it? My guess would be that the additional subview causes auto-layout to perform another calculation (or several more) and we avoid this particular single-subview bug.